# IndexBuilder and ForNpgsqlHasComment

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, ef-code-first-mapping

Why `NpgsqlEntityTypeBuilderExtensions` and `NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions` has `ForNpgsqlHasComment` method to set Comment, but `NpgsqlIndexBuilderExtensions` doesn't. How to set Comment for Index in `FluentApi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently supported. You can open an issue requesting this on https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/ (comment support has no been added to EF Core itself and will no longer be Npgsql-specific).

In the meantime you can use raw SQL in migrations to add comments to your indexes manually.